# M2 PCIe NVMe SSD driver

Tags: drivers, ssd, pcie, m2, nvme

I´m wondering if or what Ubuntu version supports my shiny new M2 PCIe 3.0 NVMe SSD (Samsung PM951 MZVLV 1TB), so Ubuntu will see it when I boot it from USB.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I asked Mr. Google and dug around a little bit.
Seems that recent versions, at least 14.04 LTS (maybe 13) support the NVMe protocol. I´ll try this.